# How to convert a datetime format like 2017-02-09T09:43:04.216+1000 to 09-Feb-2017 using python strptime and strftime?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, strftime

I have some created and updated datetime coming in dynamically from JIRA API for an automation process for getting JIRA tickets on a monthly basis using a python script to load into an excel sheet.

Some of the sample dates are as follows:

1. 2017-02-09T09:33:33.508+1100
2. 2017-05-19T13:59:36.735+1000

What I would like to present this is in a format like %d-%b-%Y (ex: 09-Feb-2017)

I have tried using python `datetime.strptime` and `strftime`.

Sample code as below:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetimeObj = datetime.strptime('2017-02-09T09:43:04.216+1000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+1000')

print(datetimeObj.strftime('%d-%b-%Y'))
```

This gives me the result as expected but now I have hardcoded the values like date I wanted and in the datetime format I have added `+1000` but since its dynamically changing datetime I get stuck when the datetime ends with values such as `+1100`.

I believe the last part is something to do with the daylight savings but I am not able find the right format for this in this case.

Is there anyway to convert the datetime format for this for the last `+1000` and `+1100` part instead of hardcoding like `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+1000'` like this?

Comment: Found the answer for this just when doing a trial and error method. ```datetimeObj = datetime.strptime('2017-02-09T09:43:04.216+1000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')``` using ```%z``` at the end solved this issue.

Comment: It looks like you don't need the actual time of the event. If so you can slice the date and then pause it by `datetime.strptime(date[:10], '%Y-%m-%d')` which can save you the trouble of pausing the remaining.

Comment: Thanks @HenryYik . It does save the trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found an answer to this. Hope this may help others too if someone else is stuck like me.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetimeObj = datetime.strptime('2017-02-09T09:43:04.216+1000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')

print(datetimeObj.strftime('%d-%b-%Y'))
```

Using `%z` will solve the problem.

`%z` is UTC offset in python `strftime()` and `strptime()` in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the the object is naive).

This helps when there are values such as `(empty), +0000, -0400, +1030` at the end of time format.

Answer (score 2):

seems you already figured out a solution but if this is always the format..

you can do:

```
date = '2017-02-09T09:33:33.508+1100'

d = re.search('[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+',date).group()
d = re.search('([0-9]+-)+[0-9]+',date).group()
d = date.split('T')[0]
d = date[0:10]
```

or some variant of this...then:

```
print(datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y'))
```

or

```
print(datetime.strptime(''.join(re.findall('\d+',date)[0:3]),'%Y%m%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y'))
```

:)

Comment: Thanks Derek. Appreciate it.